# ImportError: cannot import name 'Nullable' from 'bokeh.core.properties' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\properties.py)

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, importerror, holoviews

above the error pop up when importing the holoviews.I try different methods but didn't work. The following import

```
        import plotly.express as px
        from wordcloud import WordCloud,STOPWORDS
        import holoviews as hv
        from holoviews import opts
        hv.extension('bokeh')
        
        And installed the bokeh using pip install bokeh
produces an error:
        ImportError: cannot import name 'Nullable' from 'bokeh.core.properties' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\properti`enter code here`es.py)

        how can I fix this error?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Nullable` is a recent addition. You need to install a newer version of Bokeh.

Comment: ye I installed bokeh 2.3.2 as well as I update the pip and --use-featuer=2020 -resolver. but still have the issue, I would be grateful if you can give another solution.

Comment: Almost certainly you are not using the version of Bokeh you think you are, e.g. you have some conda or virtualenv mixup. A quick check is to print `bokeh.__version__` to confirm. Alternatively you have a corrupted install of some sort. `Nullable` is defintely part of Bokeh 2.3.2, see https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.3.2/bokeh/core/property/nullable.py

Answer (score 1):

I update the holoviews and bokeh versions, bokeh=2.3.2 holoviews=1.14 nullable is recently added the -v 2.3.2. Now it's working fine.